# Imagemagick no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: compiler-errors, imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I am trying to install Imagemagick on ubuntu 20.04 but every time i run the following command:

> magick montage frame_*.png -mode concatenate -background none -tile x1 -resize 512X512 output.svg

getting the following error:

```
montage: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
montage:  `output.svg' @ error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1806.
```

**HOW I AM COMPILING THE IMAGEMAGICK?**

1. `wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz`
2. `tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz`
3. `cd ImageMagick-7.0.11-7`
4. `$./configure`
5. `make`
6. `make install`
7. `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib`

**WHAT ELSE I HAVE TRIED?**

I have tried to modify the configure command and tried with various parameters but same problem:

```
./configure --with-png --with-rsvg --enable-shared -with-perl
```

**VERSION TEXT**

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-7 Q16 x86_64 2021-04-12 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in):
```

**WHAT I WANT?**

There are no delegates so the thing i want is to how to add delegates?
Any suggestion may help.

Comment: You are installing from source. When you do that you have to install all your delegate libraries such as for PNG, JPG, TIFF, etc before installing Imagemagick from source. I suggest that you install from binary. See https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Comment: @fmw42 thanks i was able to do it by installing all the required libraries and then enabling them through the configure command

Comment: @fmw42 i am on ubuntu 20.04, and i cant seem to find any other way to install it from binary. I just have to manually compile it according to the instructions? can you elaborate it a little bit more ?

Comment: You have no delegate libraries in your install. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042436/how-to-install-delegate-libraries-for-image-magick-7-0-7